# Selecting the first JSON result after predicate

Tags: json, json.net, jsonpath

I'm trying to write a JSON path that contains a predicate not specific enough to select a single element, yet I want to force the result to be the first one. I would like to have it done using the path only (not as part of the C# code later).

The following path returns the first book, which I expected: `$.book[0]`

The following path returns exactly two books with price > 0, which I expected: `$.book[?(@.price>20)]`

Now, I would like to return the first element from the result. I was hoping for this to work, but it doesn't. Somehow this does not work at all:

`$.book[?(@.price>20)][0]`

I am using .NET and Json.NET library, but I am open to any other.

The example JSON is as follows:

```
{
   "book":[
      {
         "title":"Beginning JSON",
         "author":"Ben Smith",
         "price":49.99
      },
      {
         "title":"JSON at Work",
         "author":"Tom Marrs",
         "price":29.99
      },
      {
         "title":"Learn JSON in a DAY",
         "author":"Acodemy",
         "price":8.99
      },
      {
         "title":"JSON: Questions and Answers",
         "author":"George Duckett",
         "price":6.00
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easy to pick the first returned item with the host language?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be built into the JSONPath language definition in any obvious way, see e.g. [Filter expression return array can not use `[index]` get item inside #272](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/272), an issue with Jayway JsonPath that has been open for nearly 5 years.  I reckon the language has no clear way to disambiguate indexing a filtered array vs indexing a 2d jagged array.  But the [JSONPath spec](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) defines `?()` so vaguely (*applies a filter (script) expression*) that maybe some workaround exists w/ Json.NET...

Comment: ... Nope.  There's even a unit test that asserts that what you want cannot be done.  See [`JPathExecuteTests.MultipleQueries()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/f7e7bd05d9280f17993500085202ff4ea150564a/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Tests/Linq/JsonPath/JPathExecuteTests.cs#L942): *`// json path does item based evaluation - http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/03/17/jsonpath-support/ // first query resolves array to ints // int has no children to query`*

Comment: The referenced article is archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20081219041955/http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/03/17/jsonpath-support/.  It draws a distinction between "Item-based" evaluation and "Result-based".  You want the latter but Json.NET's JSONPath does the former.

Comment: @Tomalak It would, but I was hoping it would be possible without it

Comment: @dbc Ah, that's a shame. Thanks for the response, feel free to post your comments as an answer.